# Build only specific pages in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, build, nuxt.js, generate

Is it possible to build or generate only specific pages from a Nuxt project? In other words, a subset of the project.

In example, let's say I have the following pages directory:

```
pages/
|
|- index.vue
|- about-us.vue
|- pricing.vue
|- moduleA
    |
    |- index.vue
    |- _id.vue
|- moduleB
    |
    |- index.vue
    |- _id.vue
```

By doing `nuxt generate`, all pages would be built and the ones that can be pre-render, will be pre-render. Is there a way of only building, for example, everything but `moduleB/`?

Right now I'm using the nuxt hook `generate:extendRoutes` to do a list of only the routes that I want to generate as suggested here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2719#issuecomment-362871101 . However, even though only those routes are generated, if one of the routes has a dependency to a module that is not in the list, it will still load that module.

i.e. If everything but `moduleB/` is generated, but `pricing.vue` has a link to `moduleB/index.vue`, you can still access it by going `/pricing => /moduleB`

What I want is a subset of the project, so that `moduleB/` is not accessible at all without having to fork the project, delete `moduleB/`, and then build that forked project. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt `generate` has an api called `exclude` that can be used to exclude certain routes from being generated. You can read more from [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#exclude).

I hope this will solve your problem